# Select Data - First entry + set time period (1 year) R

Tags: r, date, datetime, select, date-range

I have a dataset on a group of individuals that was collected starting at different times for each individual.

I need to subset the data from 1 year since their first entry, like so: `myData[myDate >= "first entry" & myDate += "1 year"]`

Example data:

```
df_date <- data.frame( Name = c("Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim",
                                "Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue"),
                       Dates = c("2010-1-1", "2010-2-2", "2010-3-5","2010-4-17","2010-5-20",
                                 "2010-6-29","2010-7-6","2010-8-9","2010-9-16","2010-10-28","2010-11-16","2010-12-28","2011-1-16","2011-2-28",
                                 "2010-4-1", "2010-5-2", "2010-6-5","2010-7-17","2010-8-20",
                                 "2010-9-29","2010-10-6","2010-11-9","2012-12-16","2011-1-28","2011-2-28","2011-3-28","2011-2-28","2011-3-28"),
                       Event = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) )
```

The desired output would be Jim would have data from `1/1/2010 - 12/28/2010` and Sue from `4/4/2010 - 3/28/2011` and so on. The actual dataset had > 20 samples, all starting at different times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a combination of `tidyverse` and `lubridate` functions:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df_date %>%
  mutate(Dates = as_datetime(Dates)) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  arrange(Dates, .by_group = T) %>%
  filter(Dates <= first(Dates) + duration(1, units = "year"))
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! Can I ask you what's happening in this line - `arrange(Dates, .by_group = T)`?

Comment: This sorts observations for each `Name` by `Dates` in increasing order such that it's meaningful to use `first()` in `filter`. Note that this step is unnecessary in www's somewhat sleeker solution which does not sort but takes the 'minimal' (i.e., earliest) date per group!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Martin C. Arnold's answer, I got another answer based on `dplyr` and `lubridate`. `min(Dates) + years(1)` means add one year to the minimum date.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df_date2 <- df_date %>%
  mutate(Dates = ymd(Dates)) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  filter(Dates <= min(Dates) + years(1)) %>%
  ungroup()
```